# Kendoui DropDownList on grid with Ajax and paramter (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI grid that uses a DropDown List.  So each element of the grid has a dropdown list.  The DropDownList is defined in a partial view.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("positions")
    .DataValueField("EmpId")
    .DataTextField("EmpName")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("_AjaxGetEmps", "Emp", new { Empid = <empid of currently selected grid row> });
        }).ServerFiltering(true);
    })
)
```

What do I put where  is?  What I'm trying to do is reference a field from the grid of the currently selected row.  Each row of the grid can have different values in the drop down and I need to pass the value into the AjaxGetEmps method.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC with the Razor view engine.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the `Empid` parameter via the Data method instead of giving directly the parameter like this :

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("positions")
    .DataValueField("EmpId")
    .DataTextField("EmpName")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("_AjaxGetEmps", "Emp")
                .Data("getCurrentEmpid"); // this links to a javascript function 
                                          // which will get the current emp id
        }).ServerFiltering(true);
    })
)
```

and the javascript function should be implemented like this :

```
function getCurrentEmpid() {
    var grid = $("#idGrid").data("kendoGrid"); // where "idGrid" is the id of your grid

    return {
        Empid: grid.dataItem(grid.select()).Empid
    }
}
```

Here `grid.select()` returns the selected line in your grid and `grid.dataItem(row)` get the data associated with this row. So here `Empid` should be the id of your model class.
Note also that if you have the flag `GridSelectionMode` to `Multiple` you will have to loop threw the `grid.select()` array...